# Trying to connect to the Dropbox API v2 using C# Receive 400 error on all attempts

Tags: c#, json, dropbox

The new Dropbox API documentation is at:

https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/a-preview-of-the-new-dropbox-api-v2/

I'm trying to execute a simple metadata call, but am having very little success.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
    private void go()
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.dropbox.com/2-beta/files/get_metadata");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"path\": \"/avatar_501.png\"}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            this.TextBox1.Text = result;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: What's the body of the 400 response? Just a guess, but your `Content-Type` header is `text/json` instead of `application/json`. I'm not sure if that's allowed or not, but the body of the error response will likely tell you the exact problem.

Comment: I also would suggest to use a web request tool ([Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for example) when you are working with API's. It's really simplifies testing. You can always first try to send request manually and when you verify that it's working, implement it in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try this code, you'll see the body of the 400 response, which tells you that `text/json` is not a valid `Content-Type`. I converted your code to a console app, and I'm using Newtonsoft.Json for the JSON serialization. Otherwise, the only difference between your code and mine is the addition of exception handling to get the body of the 400.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.dropbox.com/2-beta/files/get_metadata");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer <REDACTED>");

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
                path = "/avatar_501.png"
            }));
        }

        HttpWebResponse response;

        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Status code: {0}", (int)response.StatusCode);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Status code: 400
Error in call to API function "files/get_metadata": Bad HTTP "Content-Type" header: "text/json".  Expecting one of "application/json", "application/json; charset=utf-8", "text/plain; charset=dropbox-cors-hack".
```

Changing the `Content-Type` to `application/json` causes the call to succeed.

Comment: This solved it - also, pointing me to Newtonsoft is sure to be a big help.  I'm pretty new to using JSON, and I'm pretty sure i've been doing it the hard way.  Thank you!